# Sum columns title and columns value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

how to sum `datagridview` columns title and  columns value in `textbox` VB.net By the number of values `datagridview` columns use (For & Next)?
example

in the `datagridview` :                          before

```
          column : ID        address        

                   1         street1 

                   2         street2

                   3         street3
```

in the `textbox` :                                     after

```
                  ID = 1 / address = street1 

                  ID = 2 / address = street2 

                  ID = 3 / address = street3
```

Answer (score 0):

This little bit of code will add the values to a list, from which you can populate your textboxes. It assumes an unknown amount of columns and dgv is your DataGridView:

```
    Dim txtBoxList As New List(Of String)
    Dim strLine As String
    For Each dgvRow As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
            strLine = strLine & String.Format("{0} = {1}", dgv.Columns(i).HeaderText.ToString, dgvRow.Cells(i).tostring)
            If i < dgv.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                strLine = strLine & " / "
            End If
        Next
        txtBoxList.Add(strLine)
        strLine = String.Empty
    Next
```